# update VIN based on account name and contact name

Tags: apex

can any one suggest we have a standard object called case.we have a field called VIn no in case object.
whenever new case is created with account name and contact name,based on account name and contact name VIN should be populated.

Can anyone suggest how can i do this to get VIN no populated and VIN field is lookup here

Answer (score 1):

Actually you will want to write a before trigger so you can update the record without querying for it, putting it in a future method, or causing any additional triggers to fire....

Assuming the VIN related object also uses the account and contact as the criteria for the relationship

Something like (Update to meet your criteria as assumptions were made)

```
trigger update_vin on Case(before update, before insert){

    Set<ID> accIDs = New Set<ID>();
    Set<ID> conIDs = New Set<ID>();
    Map<String,VIN__c> keyToVIN = New Map<Stirng,VIN__c>();

    for(Case c : trigger.new){
         if(c.AccountID != null && c.ContactID != null){
             accIDs.add(c.AccountID);
             conIDs.add(c.ContactID);
         }

    }

    for(VIN__c v : [Select ID From VIN__c Where Account__c IN :accIDs AND Contact__c IN :conIDs]){
         if(keyToVin.containsKey(v.Account__c + v.Contact__c)
               //Throw error here as there is not a unique VIN Record
         else
              keyToVin.put(v.Account__c + v.Contact__c,v);
    }

   for(Case c : trigger.new){
      if(keyToVin.containsKey(c.AccountID + c.ContactID)
          c.VIN__c = keyToVin.get(c.AccountID + c.ContactID).id;

   }

}
```

Comment: I tried in this way

Comment: i tried in this way

Answer (score 0):

You could write an after trigger on case object and calculate based on the conditions to populate different  field values.